# Security of AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, security

Just now i'm writing a project, and i desided to write it with `jquery` and `ajax` requests.

only thing, i don't know, is it secure enough?

for example, when i verify the username, when registering new user, i use jquery ajax request,

i get the array of existing usernames from db(with json), and then verify, if `new_username` not `inArray()` of existing `username`s, i make another request, and register the user.

but what about security? meybe hacker can find the way to change some of my `if-else` statements, and whole my securite will brake.

maybe you'll help me to understand this situation?

Thanks

Comment: thanks much for interesting discussion. and maybe you know the methods of changing client side script? are there a tools for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you implementing *any* of that client-side?

You should send the username/password over HTTPS in an AJAX query and have the server respond with only the data required for the user to move on, **not** the whole username list.

Even putting security aside, what if you have millions of users? You're going to send that list to all clients for them to log in?

Comment: Even when using HTTPS I wouldn't send that whole list to the user; if visitors can view that list (using whatever tool) they can see who registered on your site. Moreover, don't solely rely on client-side validation; it's easy to bypass JavaScript.

Comment: it's just example, i just try to understund the working of jquery from security point of view(sorry for english language mistakes:)

Comment: Just keep in mind that anything you do on the client can be modified and viewed by the user. Any time you need to perform a secure operation, you need to have the server verify.

Answer (score 12):

*(In the following I assume, that the `username` is the ID with which a user can log in, not some kind of nickname ;))*

1. Getting all the usernames as JSON is bad. Then an attacker gets all registered usernames **immediately**!
   Just send the username to the server, validate it there and send either "valid" or "invalid" as response. I.e., check the availability on the *server side*.
2. **Always** validate the user input on the **server side**. JavaScript can be disabled.

**Update:**

It does not matter whether jQuery is involved or not. **Everything that you send to client** (and is not *hashed* or *encrypted*) **can be read by the client**, it doesn't matter whether it is an XMLHttpRequest or a "normal" request.

Would you send a HTML table with all the usernames to any visitor of your site? I hope not :)

---

**Summary:**

- Only send data, that the client is allowed to have access to.
- Validate user input on the server side.
- Never trust user input.

Comment: BTW, I know a lot of sites that send all usernames to the visitor; it's called a ‘member list’ on many forums. [Even SO does](http://stackoverflow.com/users) ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Ajax is not a replacement for server side code.  While it is possible to implement log in and registration functionality using ajax, you will still need to validate and store data on the server.

A more sane implementation would simply send an https request to the server containing the username and password to which the server would respond with a yay or nay.

Answer (score 2):

Security is one of those things that is best done server side if possible.  My typical approach to AJAX login is to send the username and an MD5 or SHA1 hashed password to a method on the server which will then take care of all of the login details.  The details of that implementation will really depend on your server-side technology, but most web application frameworks have facilities in place to do that.  There may even be some solutions which include Javascript libraries to handle the client side work as well.